# Bug no carrossel de empreendimentos

Tags: css, html5

Estou com um pequeno **bug** no modal de empreendimentos, quando abro um ele exibi ao mesmo tempo os dois, planta e ilustração, e só volta ao norma quando clico no botão...

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Segue o link do site hospedado http://mmssistemas.esy.es/Ilhc/index.php

Comment: Não sei se vai resolver, mas no `<button>` que está dentro do `<header class="headerMidia">` a classe está escrito errado. O nome seria **active** vc escreveu errado! Veja como está lá, sem a letra "**C**" *ative* `<button class="ative btn btn-outline-info showCarousel" .... >` Apesar disso não sei se vai resolver o problema principal...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marcos encontrei dois problemas na página. Um acredito ser com a classe do `<button>` que está dentro do `<header class="headerMidia">` a classe está escrita errada. O nome seria active você escreveu errado! Veja como está lá, sem a letra "C" ative `<button class="ative btn btn-outline-info showCarousel" .... >` como mencionei no comentário!

Porém o problema com o Slider é que um deles, provavelmente o "ilustração" deve está com `display:none`, já que acredito que o sei JavaScript está usando algum tipo de "toggleClass" ou `.css` para fazer isso. Porém um dos Slides já deve iniciar com o `display:none` definido.

Para entender melhor veja nas imagens.

Imagem original com o BUG, **repare que não tem dispaly definido e nenhum dos dois Sliders**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Agora repare que quando você clica nos Botões ele começa a altera o tipo do Display entre um Botão e outro!***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Então basta adicionar `display:none` no segundo Slider por exemplo para tudo funcionar certinho, provavelmente sem precisar mexer no script que você já tem.**

Comment: Caramba, resolveu na hora... muito obrigado brother me salvou aqui, era coisa muito simples! Vou ter que estudar mais hehehe

Comment: As vezes não percebemos esse detalhes, boa sorte com o projeto!